# Qt TouchBegin touchPoint.pos() is stuck at 0,0

Tags: android, c++, qt, touch-event

I am coding an android application in QT and when the TouchEvent is emitted my touchEvent->touchPoints().at(newPoint).pos() is always 0,0 until I move my finger and force a TouchUpdate event. Is there a way to get the position on TouchBegin? Below is my event code:

```
bool event(QEvent* e)
{
    switch(e->type())
    {
        case QEvent::TouchBegin:
        touchEvent = static_cast<QTouchEvent*>(e);
        emit touchBegin();
            emit touchUpdate();
            return true;
        case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
            touchEvent = static_cast<QTouchEvent*>(e);
            emit touchUpdate();
            return true;
        case QEvent::TouchEnd:
            emit touchEnd();
            return true;
        default:
            return QWidget::event(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it. I was using the global position when what I needed to use was touchEvent.touchPoints().at(currentPoint).pos().x() or .y() and if it was in a frame or widget I needed to get the global position from that point.